# Best way to combine Google for Work with postfix mail server / e-mail routing

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, g-suite, gmail

I am re-designing our company mail services, and we are migrating some mail-boxes to Google for Work. The objective is to have some users in the cloud, and some users on an on-premise Postfix server.

I have currently configured DNS with GMail MX records and configured GMail to forward all mail for unknown users to my Postfix server.

Whenever I send an e-mail from GMail (personal or business), the e-mail gets properly delivered to a correct Postfix mailbox. However, if I try to send e-mail from Postfix to GMail for Work user , I get an error message from Postfix.

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; glczwe-sp230001.ext.*filtered*
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: AFB0A86F24
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; petr.balla@*filtered*
Arrival-Date: Tue,  9 Feb 2016 20:43:48 +0100 (CET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; dl-cz-accounting@*filtered*
Original-Recipient: rfc822;dl-cz-accounting@*filtered*
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: x-unix; user unknown
```

Obviously, Postfix handles the domain, so it rejects the e-mail, because the account does not exist locally. I know I could list all the users in */etc/postfix/transport*, however I am trying to think of a way that would be easier from a mailbox provisioning perspective. Having to touch both mail-servers, GMail and Postfix when creating new users on a GMail servers is a bit of a pain for my taste.

Does anybody have an idea about a solution for my problem? I believe ith might be very common scenario for all Google for Work users.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the value of maintaining two separate email systems with users spread across both?

Comment: Reduction in service costs. This hybrid solution will cut solution costs roughly to half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to run *two* mail servers on premise. One handles  only incoming mail, while the other handles only outgoing mail and knows nothing of the first server.